# different byobu screens on large cluster depending on the login node

Tags: ssh, byobu

I am trying to use byobu on a large cluster, where I internally get connected to a different login node each time I ssh to the cluster. Normally, one wouldn't even realize the difference, but when I try to use screen or byobu, I get connected to one individual session per login node. Have you ever encountered such a problem and could you think of a way
to synchronize it?

Comment: A couple of questions...  When you say you "ssh to the cluster", how are you determining which system in the cluster you get connected to?

Comment: Do you want to type one command and have it run on every machine in the cluster?  Is that what you mean by "synchronize it"?

Comment: Or, are you trying to ssh to the cluster, get assigned a random machine, start running byobu there, run some program (like top), detach, ssh back in, and have your byobu session running top "moved" to the machine that you go magically assigned?

Comment: The latter, i.e. one byobu session per login, irrespective of the login node. And to answer your first question: I can see the difference in the hostname after login. they are numbered from 1 to 4. So username@clustername#, where # stands for the number of the login node.

Comment: @Florian I converted your "answer" to a comment for you. Check out the [about] page for more details on how the question/answer system on Super User works. Answers are for listing solutions, while comments are used for clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

So [Byobu](http://byobu.co) is a process (or, rather `tmux` or `screen`) is an operating system process that runs on a given node.  There's no way to move or migrate the underlying process from one node to another, which is unfortunate to your use case.  If you want to reattach to a particular Byobu session, you would need some way of navigating through your cluster gateway to the "right" system.  I'm sorry Byobu can't be of more help you you here.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Thank you for using appropriate disclosure of your affiliation with this project! Lots of people forget to do that.